# Laravel error must be an instance of.. Chat application

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have problem. I use event: https://github.com/musonza/chat/blob/master/src/Messages/MessageWasSent.php

In my controller:

```
public function sendMessage(Conversation $conversation, Request $request) {
    $v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
         'message' => 'required|string|max:4000',
    ]);

    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    $conv = Chat::conversation($conversation->id);

    Chat::message($request->message)
        ->from($user)
        ->to($conv)
        ->send();

    event(new MessageWasSent($request->message));
}
```

I get error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Musonza\Chat\Messages\MessageWasSent::__construct() must be an instance of Musonza\Chat\Messages\Message, string given..
```

In my app.js:

```
send(){
        if(this.message.length != 0 && this.message.length <= 4000) {
            this.chat.message.push(this.message);
            this.chat.user.push(this.user);
            this.chat.time.push(this.getTime());
            axios.post('/sendMessage/' + this.convId, {
                message: this.message,
              })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.message = '';
              })
              .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }
    }
```

Routes:

```
    Route::post('sendMessage/{conversation}', 'Chat\ChatController@sendMessage')->name('chatsend');
```

How I can fix this error?

Comment: As Your error says:  you need to give instance of message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message = Chat::message($request->message)
        ->from($user)
        ->to($conv)
        ->send();

event(new MessageWasSent($message));
```

As the error says the event constructor requires an instance of `Musonza\Chat\Messages\Message` rather than a string,